# Autoinstall storage: not working, Ubuntu does its own thing 20.04

Tags: 20.04, cloud-init, autoinstall

I'm working with Ubuntu 20.40, where I'm creating an ISO with the user-data/meta-data on the image, then booting a VMware VM off it.   I watch the output, it seems to create the logical volumes and mount points; it installs software, the user I configured, updates etc., but every time I end up with a filesystem I didn't ask for.  I've put this through YAML validators, validated it with cloud-init, compared it to other configs and I cannot figure out what the problem is.

I stripped it all down to just the basics and it still does the same thing.  Here's the user-data (sanitized):

```
 #cloud-config autoinstall:   version: 1   # Reboot doesn't work   shutdown: reboot   apt:
     geoip: true
     preserve_sources_list: false
     primary:
     - arches: [amd64]
       uri: http://mirror.domain.com/ubuntu
     - arches: [default]
       uri: http://mirror.domain.com/ubuntu-ports   keyboard: {layout: us, toggle: null, variant: ''}   locale: en_US   user-data:
     disable_root: false
     users:
       - default
       - name: username
         gecos: Gecos Name
         ssh-authorized-keys:
           - ssh-ed25519 OMITTED
         passwd: OMITTED
         lock_passwd: false
         shell: /bin/bash
         groups: adm, sudo, root
         sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL   packages: [openssh-server, build-essential, htop, chrony, vim, clevis, clevis-luks,
     dracut-network, oddjob, oddjob-mkhomedir, cups-client, yp-tools, postfix, libopenscap8,
     aide, crypto-policies, firefox, perl, git, build-essential]   ssh:
     allow-pw: true
     authorized-keys: []
     install-server: true storage:   grub:
     reorder_uefi: false
     config:
       - {ptable: gpt, path: /dev/sda, wipe: superblock, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: true,
         type: disk, id: disk-sda}
       - {device: disk-sda, size: 5M, flag: bios_grub, number: 1, preserve: false,
         type: partition, id: partition-0}
       - {device: disk-sda, size: 1G, flag: '', number: 2, preserve: false, type: partition, id: partition-1}
       - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-1, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-1}
       - {device: disk-sda, size: -1, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 3, preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id:
 partition-2 }
       - {name: system, devices: [ partition-2 ], preserve: false, type: lvm_volgroup, id: lvm_volgroup-0 }
       - {name: root, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 70G, wipe: superblock, preserve: false, type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-0}
       - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-0, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-2}
       - {path: /, device: format-2, type: mount, id: mount-2}
       - {name: tmp, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 15G, wipe: superblock, preserve: false, type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-1}
       - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-1, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-3}
       - {path: /tmp, device: format-3, type: mount, id: mount-3}
       - {name: var, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 15G, wipe: superblock, preserve: false, type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-2}
       - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-2, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-4}
       - {path: /var, device: format-4, type: mount, id: mount-4}
       - {name: varlogaudit, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 15G, wipe: superblock, preserve: false, type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-3}
       - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-3, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-5}
       - {path: /var/log/audit, device: format-5, type: mount, id: mount-5}
```

When I'm done and I reboot the VM, the filesystem looks like this.  There is plenty of disk space (250GB) and 10GB of RAM.  Resources aren't the issue.  The cloud-init logs don't say anything obvious to me (there's a lot in there):

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              995M  1.2M  994M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  122G  7.0G  109G   6% /
tmpfs                              4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          974M  111M  796M  13% /boot
/dev/loop1                          70M   70M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19188
/dev/loop2                          32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/10707
/dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1944
tmpfs                              995M     0  995M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I can't see what's going wrong here.

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably getting the default `lvm` layout.  Your `user-data` appears to have pasted incorrectly so it is impossible to tell if your `storage` section is correct.  The `storage` node should be nested under the `autoinstall` node, and the `grub` and `config` nodes are nested under the `storage` node.

Comment: Yeah, the result of copy and paste.  I have found the free VSCode editor to be a blessing with YAML files.

Answer (score 0):

This my storage>config section

```
storage:
    config:
    #DEVICE
    - {ptable: gpt, path: /dev/xvda, wipe: superblock, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: true, type: disk, id: disk-sda}
    #PARTITION 0: GRUB 1048576 bytes = 1 MB
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 1048576, flag: bios_grub, number: 1, preserve: false,
      grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-0}
    #PARTITION 1 /BOOT PARTITION : 1073741824 bytes = 1GB
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 2,
      preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-1} 
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-1, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-0}
    - {path: /boot, device: format-0, type: mount, id: mount-0}
    #PARTITION 2 / VOLUME GROUP
    - {device: disk-sda, size: -1, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 3, preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-2}
    - name: ubuntu-vg
      devices: [partition-2]
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
    #/ROOT  
    - {name: ubuntu-lv-root, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 20%, wipe: superblock,preserve: false, type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-0}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-0, preserve: false, type: format, id: lvmformat-0}
    - {path: /, device: lvmformat-0, type: mount, id: lvmmount-0}
    #/HOME  
    - {name: ubuntu-lv-home, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock,preserve: false, type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-1}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-1, preserve: false, type: format, id: lvmformat-1}
    - {path: /home, device: lvmformat-1, type: mount, id: lvmmount-1}
    #/TMP
    - {name: ubuntu-lv-tmp, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock,preserve: false, type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-2}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-2, preserve: false, type: format, id: lvmformat-2}
    - {path: /tmp, device: lvmformat-2, type: mount, id: lvmmount-2}
    #/VAR/LOG/AUDIT
    - {name: ubuntu-lv-audit, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock,preserve: false, type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-3}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-3, preserve: false, type: format, id: lvmformat-3}
    - {path: /var/log/audit, device: lvmformat-3, type: mount, id: lvmmount-3}
    #/VAR/LOG
    - {name: ubuntu-lv-log, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock,preserve: false, type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-4}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-4, preserve: false, type: format, id: lvmformat-4}
    - {path: /var/log, device: lvmformat-4, type: mount, id: lvmmount-4}
    #/VAR/TMP
    - {name: ubuntu-lv-vtmp, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock,preserve: false, type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-5}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-5, preserve: false, type: format, id: lvmformat-5}
    - {path: /var/tmp, device: lvmformat-5, type: mount, id: lvmmount-5}
    #SWAP
    - {name: ubuntu-lv-swap, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 2147483648, wipe: superblock,preserve: false, type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-6}
    - {fstype: swap, volume: lvm_partition-6, preserve: false, type: format, id: lvmformat-6}
    #/VAR  
    - {name: ubuntu-lv-var, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, wipe: superblock,preserve: false, type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-7}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-7, preserve: false, type: format, id: lvmformat-7}
    - {path: /var, device: lvmformat-7, type: mount, id: lvmmount-7}
```

above config will create this following storage layout

```
xvda                                            20G 
├─xvda1                                          1M 
├─xvda2                          ext4            1G /boot
└─xvda3                          LVM2_member    19G 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv--root  ext4          3.8G /
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv--home  ext4            1G /home
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv--tmp   ext4            1G /tmp
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv--audit ext4            1G /var/log/audit
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv--log   ext4            1G /var/log
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv--vtmp  ext4            1G /var/tmp
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv--swap  swap            2G 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv--var   ext4          8.2G /var
```

I intentionally removed the 'size' parameter in the 'var' section. The documentation states that we can input -1 to fill the remaining space, but it didn't work in my case, which was lacking around 2 bytes.

I didn't find adequate information about this, so I hope it will help anyone else who stumbles upon the same problem.